# Should I declare array size for int?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm beginner of C programming and using visual stdio 2015.

For example,

```
double i = 0;
double array[10][3];
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    array[i][0] = i;
    array[i][1] = i*i;
    array[[i][2] = i*i*i;
}
```

This code have some errors. I think declare i for double is problem. Should I using I for int?

Comment: *This code have some errors* has zero meaning unless you also include what *errors* you're getting. There is no reason you should not provide it in your question - it's on your screen right in front of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think declare i for double is problem.

Yes.

You compiler should report the error that you are using a `double` as an index in an array. Using gcc, I get the following error.

```
soc.c:9:12: error: array subscript is not an integer
       array[i][0] = i;

soc.c:10:12: error: array subscript is not an integer
       array[i][1] = i*i;
            ^
soc.c:11:12: error: array subscript is not an integer
       array[i][2] = i*i*i;
         ^
```

> Should I using I for int?

Yes.